# Gradle 'implementation' dependency isn't compile with correct code

Tags: java, gradle, compiler-errors, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

I have a compilation issue with **implementation** dependency when compiling with Gradle the following project that contains of 3 modules:

- test-impl
- test-lib
- my-test

My error:

```
/Users/igor/projects/my-test/src/main/java/MyTest.java:4: error: cannot access TestImpl
        lib.foo("");
           ^
  class file for TestImpl not found
```

It is compiled when I change `implemention` to `api` or if I rename any of `foo` methods in `TestLib` class.

Gradle 6.0.1, Java 1.8.0_271-b09, OSX

Doesn't it look like a bug? Where to report?

## All build.gradle files:

Module **test-impl** `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
```

Module **test-lib** `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':test-impl')
}
```

Module **my-test** `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    api project(':test-lib')
}
```

## All source codes:

`TestImpl.java` in **test-impl** module:

```
public class TestImpl {
}
```

`TestLib.java` in **test-lib** module:

```
public class TestLib {
    public void foo(String s) {
    }

    private void foo(TestImpl impl) {
    }
}
```

`MyTest.java` in **my-test** module:

```
public class MyTest {
    public void test() {
        TestLib lib = new TestLib();
        lib.foo("");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `foo` method is overloaded, so maybe the compiler tries to resolve the two methods to figure out which one to use and fails in the second one as the class used for the parameter is not available (by design). Looking at it, it is clear it can only choose the public method but maybe that logic is only applied after the full method signature for both are parsed. Interesting problem...

Comment: Thank you for you comment.
I tried to post it to gradle's github, but it was closed there by Louis Jacomet (ljacomet).
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15660